# Вывод сырого HTML на странице

Tags: laravel, blade

Как можно вывести сырой HTML на страницу?
В базе у меня есть текст, который нужно вывести в таком виде на страницу

```
<p><strong>Patient Name: {{patient_name}}
```

При рендере `{{patient_name}}` удаляется. Мне нужно, чтобы он остался.
Пробую вывести вот так:

```
>{{html_entity_decode($template->content)}}</textarea>
>{!! $template->content !!}</textarea>
```

Оба варианта не работают.

Comment: Попробуйте тег <pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Так как у меня подключён `VUE` на странице. Нужно было добавить атрибут к textarea `v-pre`

Comment: Хм. Судя по всему вы не хотите использовать [v-html](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#%D0%A1%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-HTML), типа читаете из базы свой сырой html и хотите чтобы в базе все эти `{{` и `}}` были? Всё-таки как-то не особо красиво, я бы варианту с `pre` предпочёл бы избавиться от хранения переменных в сыром html.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно хранить в базе `{{ }}`
Это работает как шаблон при выводе результата.
Поэтому без них никак, но спасибо за совет)